# Check hash (MD4, MD5, SHA-1, and CRC) on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10

Tags: md5sum, hash

I have a lot of iso-files downloaded from internet. I want to check the hash from my Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10. Is there any application on Ubuntu to check the MD4, MD5, SHA-1, and CRC hash?

I need the CRC hash-checker to check my Windows 8 iso files.

Comment: Also related https://askubuntu.com/q/474130/295286

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Er for MD5 and SHA1 you can do

```
md5sum (file name)
```

for md5sum and

```
sha1sum (file name)
```

for sha1sum in terminal. But then I don't understand why you need CRC sums for Windows 8 since I think the official checksums are for sha1.