# How to check crc of a file?

Tags: command-line, checksums

I was looking [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203604/check-hash-md4-md5-sha-1-and-crc-on-ubuntu-12-04-and-12-10) and appears everything but crc. Is there a good Ubuntu way around there to do this?

Comment: CRC means Cyclic Redundancy check.  It's a type of (insecure) hash, rather than a specific standard.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check lists many kinds of CRC.  (CRC32 is perhaps the most common.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libarchive-zip-perl
$ crc32 my_file
```

Comment: `perl-Archive-Zip` in fedora, mind you

Comment: Very helpful for comparing that a file inside a JAR is the correct version.

Comment: Adding to what Nemo said, for CentOs, Redhat, Fedora, and similar distros the library is installed with `yum install perl-Archive-Zip`

Answer (score 18):

One way to calculate it is this:

```
cksum "file"
```

Another one is

```
crc32 "file"
```

To use this last command you need to install `libarchive-zip-perl` package

Comment: `cksum`is not compatible with `crc32`, it uses different algorithm

Comment: I don't know which type of CRC the OP had, but the version of `cksum` on my Linux box (a Synology NAS unit) can produce four different outputs. One with no parameters (`cksum file`) but it also accepts `-o1` through `-o3` options. Using `-o3` produces the same value as used in "CSV verification files" (albeit it produces them in decimal, the files have them in hex)... that _might_ be the same algorithm as the OP needs.

Comment: @TripeHound The cksum version (9.1) currently in debian 12 doesn't seem to have any -o1 through -o3 algorithms. But it does have the -a / --algorithm options, however none appear to match the crc32 from libarchive-zip-perl, cksfv, or rhash. Even cksum's `crc` algorithm outputs a decimal number that does not convert to the same hex the others report

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the internal `md5sum` one of the provided sha programs:

```
sha1sum (1)          - compute and check SHA1 message digest
sha224sum (1)        - compute and check SHA224 message digest
sha256sum (1)        - compute and check SHA256 message digest
sha384sum (1)        - compute and check SHA384 message digest
sha512sum (1)        - compute and check SHA512 message digest
```

`cksum` is pretty much outmoded these days because of its problems.

Comment: What problems? I want to know if two files are duplicates - is `cksum` not good enough for that purpose?

Comment: Perhaps the "problem" is the fact that CRC is not a cryptographic hash (meaning it's considered easy to create two files with different contents that have the same CRC if that's what you're trying to do). However, when you're talking about random errors, CRC is not too bad AFAIK.

Comment: CRC is about 10x faster than md5 in my current tests. So CRC vs md5/sha involves a tradeoff between key space (probability of accidental collision) and performance. In a small device or with high data volume performance might matter.

Answer (score 4):

`cksfv` app from `cksfv` package generates CRC32 checksum as well.

Comment: could you give a usage example?

Comment: `cksfv -c "file"` prints the CRC32 to stdout. If you want to suppress the header, a `cksfv -c "file" 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^\;` gives the filename + CRC32 and no warning for a directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `rhash`.

- http://rhash.sourceforge.net/
- https://github.com/rhash/RHash
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rhash.1.html

Test:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install rhash
$ echo -n 123456789 | rhash --simple -
cbf43926  (stdin)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this with a very simple perl script.
use String::CRC32;

```
my $s = <STDIN>;

my $crc = crc32($s);
printf "%08x\n", $crc;
```

Comment: Sounds good, but how can someone with zero perl knowledge turn this into a working answer? Or even a one liner?