# Is there an alternative for the Windows software "hashcheck" in Ubuntu?

Tags: md5sum, hash

`hashcheck` **checks** for matches of **many common** hash codes. (See http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/)

Is there an alternative for this software for Windows on Ubuntu?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I don't see how this isn't a question.. He wants an alternative for some Windows software.

Answer (score 4):

Most sum checking utilities are already included in Linux as command line programs - a few can be listed by running `ls $(echo $PATH | sed -e s/:/' '/g) | grep sum` (which searches the directories of executables to find filenames containing `sum`) :

```
sum
cksum
md5sum
md5sum-lite
sha1sum
sha224sum
sha256sum
sha384sum
sha512sum
shasum
sum
```

So you can get the md5 sum by running:

```
md5sum /PATH/TO/FILE(S)
```

and the sha1 sum by running:

```
sha1sum /PATH/TO/FILE(S)
```

For other commands (although these usually use a similar syntax), you can search for their usage & options online or by using `man`ual or help commands:

```
man cksum
cksum --help
```

MD4: I do not think has been used or included much outside of Windows for a few years due security concerns, although the `rhash` package appears to support it.

If you want a GUI, as [this suggests](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/12/checksum-verifier-ubuntu-linux/), you can use [this:](http://sourceforge.net/projects/akis-sideris.u/files/)

[image]

or other similar packages like `gtkhash`, which look like they can integrate into Ubuntu's file managers. Otherwise, you may be able to run it under [Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 0):

## GtkHash

```
$ sudo apt install gtkhash
```

[image: GtkHash]