# How to wget the most recent AMD SDK?

Tags: ati, wget

I would like to script the install for the OpenCL SDK from AMD which I can find [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/)

Naturally I assumed a simple `wget` call would work.

```
wget http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64.tgz
```

But when I try to extract the `tgz` file I get the following error:

```
tar -zxvf AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64.tgz 

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Did I make some simple error or is there some other way to get the most recent 'stable' SDK from AMD from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Eliah pointed out, this is happening because you are downloading an incorrect file by using `wget`. This can be confirmed by comparing the downloaded files MD5 checksum to the one listed on the [AMD checksum reference page](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/). The archive downloaded using `wget` will have a different checksum than the one listed on that page.

- If you download `AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64.tgz` from the [AMD website](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/#), you will need to agree to a License Agreement before being able to download it.
- If you use wget to download the SDK, you will not be agreeing to the license agreement and thus, archive will have the wrong MD5 Checksum:

  - `MD5 (AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64.tgz) = 649b53fccfa8262de835d554fdd56dfc`
- However, if you download it properly from the website, the checksum will be:

  - `MD5 (AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64 (1).tgz) = 24ca89856d41aa82dea8370b7a24fb4e`

AMD lists the correct checksums on [this page](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/).

So, in order to download it using a script, you will most likely have to upload the correctly downloaded archive somewhere else. However, this may be against the License Agreement, I'm not sure. I copied AMD's license agreement to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sbolel/36aac44beac38e72c1f5) if you'd like to take a look.

You can refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/203626/77449) for how to check the md5sum. Copied from the answer:

> for MD5 and SHA1 you can do
>
> `md5sum (file name)`
>
> for md5sum and
>
> `sha1sum (file name)`

Comment: The problem is not that the file's checksum is wrong, but that it is altogether the wrong file. The checksum is an *indication* of this--if both files were the same, they would of course have the same checksum too--but it is not itself the underlying problem. Sometimes an operation fails because a checksum is wrong, but that's not happening here: `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format` means it's not a gzipped file at all, not that checksum verification (which `tar` and `gz` do not actually perform) failed. Besides that, though, this is a correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification! I'll edit the answer to reflect this info.

Comment: This is what I suspected but I am admittedly disappointed.  I will need to read the agreement carefully to see if I can just upload it elsewhere for my script to work properly.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is actually in the error message: `not in gzip format`.
So If you just remove 'z' form  -zxvf it should work. Like this:

`tar -xvf AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64.tgz`