# libpng warning : Application jmp_buf size changed - while installing XAMPP

Tags: 18.04, xampp

I'm in Ubuntu 18.04.1. When I try to install the lastest version of xampp after changing the permission (with `sudo chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-7.3.1-0-installer.run`) and then installing (with the command `sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.1-0-installer.run`), I have a error message:

> warning: Application jmp_buf size changed.
>
> Segmentation fault

And I can't install it. I didn't find the answer to my problem, can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually I didn't need to solve it by myself. It was the problem with that version of Xampp or a bug in Ubuntu itself. I downloaded Xampp again after one moth and Voilà!!, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue by deleting the noto font (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto).

See more detailed description in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213079/736759)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is almost certainly a problem with the software package you are installing.  It could be that it got corrupted during download - in which case you should download it again or it could be that it's buggy in the first place - in which case you should report it back to the distributors.  In any case the correct place for questions is the XMPP community - https://www.apachefriends.org/community.html - people on Ask Ubuntu won't be able to help beyond telling you that it's a software problem.

To be sure that software that you have downloaded isn't corrupted then check the checksums.

You can get XMPP checksums here - https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Instructions for checking checksums are here - [Check hash (MD4, MD5, SHA-1, and CRC) on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203604/check-hash-md4-md5-sha-1-and-crc-on-ubuntu-12-04-and-12-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)

As an alternative you could just go into the Ubuntu software centre and install

- apache
- mariadb
- PHP
- perl

and then you would have a similar setup to the one that XAMPP gives you.

If your problems do persist even after installing the Ubuntu versions of the software then it is most likely a hardware corruption issue.  Look up questions about that.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but when I tried to intalll apache2, the server was failed to start, and apache2 was not able to install.